# Remove attribute scroll spy Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a script Angular.JS and I have a smooth scroll on my page with a scrollspy, so all the menu animates when I do the scrolling of all the page normal but I don't want it, I want to disable the scroll spy and reactivate after.

I tried to remove the attribute scrollspy before the scrolling et reactivate after but the scroll spy works again I don't know why.

This is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.scroll').click( function() { // Au clic sur un élément

            $('.nav a.scroll').removeAttr('du-scrollspy');

            var page = $(this).attr('href'); // Page cible
            var speed = 750; // Durée de l'animation (en ms)
            var top = $(page).offset().top-24;
            $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: top }, speed ); // Go

            $('.nav a.scroll').attr('du-scrollspy',"");

            return false;
        });
    });

<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li>
        <a class="scroll" href="#section1_1" du-scrollspy offset="20">Section1_1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="scroll" href="#section1_2" du-scrollspy offset="20">Section1_2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="scroll" href="#section1_3" du-scrollspy offset="20">Section1_3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I use this scroll spy because a have a script angularJS : https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll

Comment: try this $('.nav a.scroll').removeAttr('du-scrollspy');

Comment: Thanks but I do already that in the beginning of my function ^^